# Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both Error while building for ios

Tags: flutter

Error when running flutter build ios on macbook air m1

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           15.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[20705]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x203096c10) and
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x115d682b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[20705]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x203096c60) and
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x115d68308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: Same problem here while launching a git command.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this is due when i implement firebase auth. that requires us to add  configuration guide point number 3 and number 4.

when i don't do that, it resolved and everything works.

please refer to this link for more [click this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72492#issuecomment-791890194)

hope it will solve too